# Is it Possible to Index into an Object Using String Keys From a Dynamic Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to dynamically set keys when using this syntax as shown in this example?

In this example, the `changeValue` function changes the state object show at the top. The `changeValue` function takes an array of string keys to be used as a way to dynamically set the value.

**This code does not work and I am not looking for alternative approaches:** (within reasonable alternation)

```js
const state = {
    profile: {
        isFollowing: false,
    },
    person: {
        characteristics: {
            gender: "male"
        }
    }
}




console.log(state.profile.isFollowing) //false
console.log(state.person.characteristics.gender) //male
function changeValue(keys, value){
    state[keys] = value
}
console.log(state.profile.isFollowing) //true
console.log(state.person.characteristics.gender) //female




changeValue(["profile", "isFollowing"], true) //<-- using an array of strings
//AFTER STATE CHANGE
//const state = {
//    profile: {
//        isFollowing: true,
//    },
//    person: {
//       characteristics: {
//            gender: "male"
//        }
//    }
//}




changeValue(["person", "characteristics", "gender"], "female") //<-- using an array of strings
//AFTER STATE CHANGE
//const state = {
//    profile: {
//        isFollowing: true,
//    },
//    person: {
//       characteristics: {
//            gender: "female"
//        }
//    }
//}
```

I don't want to have to manually define the `[keys]` within the `changeValue` function.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't just index into an object with an array and have it automatically descend hierarchically. There are modules you can install that let you do similar things; for example, check out [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s [`set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) method. You have to join the array into a single `.`-separated key path string, but it's basically what you're looking for.

However, it's also pretty easy to do it yourself in vanilla JS with a loop:

```
function changeValue(keyPath, newValue) {
    let target = state
    let key = keyPath[0]
    for (let i=1; i<keyPath.length; ++i) {
        target = target[key]
        key = keyPath[i]
    }
    target[key] = newValue;
}
```

Here it is in action:

```js
const state = {
    profile: {
        isFollowing: false,
    },
    person: {
        characteristics: {
            gender: "male"
        }
    }
}

function changeValue(keyPath, newValue) {
    let target = state
    let key = keyPath[0]
    for (let i=1; i<keyPath.length; ++i) {
        target = target[key]
        key = keyPath[i]
    }
    target[key] = newValue;
}

changeValue(["profile", "isFollowing"], true);
changeValue(["person", "characteristics", "gender"], "female")
console.log(state);
```

Comment: Dang, I wish we could. It is what it is though. I would appreciate if you could name those modules, that would be helpful.

Comment: Probably the most common module is lodash.get: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get which takes a string of JS-looking syntax for object/array access, so you could do something like `_.get(state, ["profile", "isFollowing"].join("."))`

Comment: (There is also lodash.set which accepts the new value as the third param)

Comment: Updated with links to lodash. But note that the function in my answer lets you call `changeValue` exactly as in your post (in fact I pasted from your question into my snippet), so I'm not sure what your objection to the solution is.

Comment: @MarkReed I don't, I'm just waiting the 5 minutes to accept your answer. I was also interested in the lodash module after you brang it up.

Answer (score 4):

Sure thing. A helper function like this should do the trick.

```js
const state = {
  profile: {
    isFollowing: false,
  },
  person: {
    characteristics: {
      gender: "male"
    }
  }
}

function changeValue(target, path, value) {
  for(let i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
    target = target[path[i]];
  }
  target[path[path.length - 1]] = value;
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
changeValue(state, ["profile", "isFollowing"], true);
console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
changeValue(state, ["person", "characteristics", "gender"], "female");
console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be to use reduce to work up the object until you get to the last item and then set it's value.

```js
const state = { profile: { isFollowing: false, }, person: { characteristics: { gender: "male" } } }

function changeValue(keys, value){
  keys.slice(0,-1).reduce((acc, k) => acc[k], state)[keys.slice(-1)] = value
}

changeValue(["profile", "isFollowing"], true);
console.log(state);

changeValue(["person", "characteristics", "gender"], "female");
console.log(state);
```